# $\mathrm{d} \Omega_{CM}$ for a $1\rightarrow 2$ particle decay?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering, perturbation-theory

The differential solid angle is described in e.g. [Srednicki's QFT](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf#page=97) text but only for the case of scattering. Because in the case of scattering it's defined with respect to the incoming three-momentum ${\bf k_1}$ and it's scattered three-momentum ${\bf k_1'}$. This definition would not make much sense for a particle decay (I can't at least see how it would easily carry over).

What about the case of **particle decay**? What is $$\mathrm{d} \Omega_{CM}$$ in the case of particle decay? Any good references where it is properly defined?

Comment: It is a solid angle, but its definition depends on the particular case. How many particles you have in the final state? Check "Elementary Particles and Their Interactions", Quang Ho-Kim.

Comment: The title mentions 1->2 particle decay. Do you have any idea about the answer? Thanks for replying.

Comment: Ok, sorry. See the answer and comment below. There is nothing special about this angle.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 4-momentum must be conserved, there is no angular dependence in a 2-body decay in the CM frame. But If you are asking yourself what is the phase-space of such process, you should take a look at equation 4.72 of the book I mentioned in the comments:

$$\Gamma(M\to 1 + 2)=\dfrac{|\vec{p_1}|}{32 \pi^2 M^2} \int \mathrm{d}\Omega |\mathcal{M}|^2=\dfrac{|\vec{p_1}|}{8 \pi M^2}|\mathcal{M}|^2,$$

where $\mathcal{M}$ is the amplitude of the process, $M$ is the mass of the initial particle and $|\vec{p_1}|=|\vec{p_2}|$ is the final 3-momentum of one of the particles.

Comment: Yes I know it's $4\pi$ in this case, but I mean, how is it defined. Because in the case of scattering it's defined with respect to the incoming three-momentum ${\bf k_1}$ and it's scattered three-momentum ${\bf k_1'}$. This definition would not make much sense for a particle decay (I can't at least see how it would carry over in any sense).

Comment: It is the angle of one of the particles with respect to a given axis. Since the amplitude does not depend on this angle, you have only $4\pi$. 

Think in terms of the general formula for the phase-space: $\mathrm{d}\phi_f \propto \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 p_1}{2 E_1}\frac{\mathrm{d}^3 p_2}{2 E_2} \delta^4(p_1+p_2-p)$. We integrate the momentum of one of the particles to get rid of the distribution $\delta^3$ and at the end we'll have only a 3D integral. To do this integral, you have to define an angle.